# Laravel queues large memory leak

Tags: php, laravel, memory-leaks

I am using Laravel queues with redis.
In my queue job I do the following things:
- make two queries with Eloquent
- make 10-15 requests to external API
- resize and upload images (up to 10)

And just for 1 minute memory usage uncreases to 5-6 GB until all memory (about 40GB) is eaten and the server goes down.

Config: PHP 5.6, Laravel 5.3.

What may cause the memory leak?

Comment: Your code may cause a memory leak. Can you please share it?

Comment: @apokryfos it is pretty long and includes lots of references to other classes, so it is a problem to share it here. There are a few eloquent selects and updates and as I said previously, there are requests to external API with curl extension + images uploading to external API. I was told that PHP begins to fork itself when there were memory leaks.

Comment: PHP does not fork itself. Chances are you're allocating data but not freeing it when you're done with it. Use `$variable = null;` as soon and as often as possible to ensure that the garbage collector can free up memory for you. If that still doesn't work then you should stream large API responses into files and stream SQL queries row by row instead of all at one go.